# How do I find out how deep underwater I have to be to get a specific pressure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, pressure, water, fluid-statics

This is a question I had on my test:

> A person with heels has a mass of 58 kg. The area of the heel is $1.4\ cm^2$. How deep underwater would the pressure be the same as if the person would stand on one heel? The pressure on the water surface is 1020 mbar.

Unfortunately I couldn't figure it out, but this is what I did.

The pressure underwater

$$p_1=h\cdot p\cdot g$$

The pressure when the person stands on one heel

$$p_2=\frac{58kg\cdot9.81m/s^2}{0.00014m^2}$$

Now I know the pressure that is wanted is $p_2=4064142.8571429pa$

So $$h=\frac{4064142.8571429pa}{9.81m/s^2\cdot p_{density}}$$

And this is the point where I got to, I think the pressure at water surface is something I haven't used. How should I continue?

Comment: All that pressure of air on the water's surface adds to the pressure of the water at a given depth.

Comment: Does it mean that $h=\frac{4064142.8571429pa +1020mbar}{9.81m/s^2\cdot p_{density}}$? @electronpusher

Comment: The fun way, of course, is to scuba dive with a pressure gauge. But I'm an experimentalist at heart. Be sure to compare fresh water to sea water.

Answer (score 0):

At a depth of 33 feet, the pressure is one atmosphere (15PSIG) and you add 15 psi for each additional 33 feet of depth.

Comment: Ok, so my calculations were useless?

Comment: no. I did the calculation for you, and you need to understand how to do it.

Comment: @Student776 try doing what I suggested and see if you arrive at that value provided by Niels

Answer (score 0):

According to your conditions- fluid pressure due to liquid column weight equals to person pressure due to it's weight :
$$ \rho gh = \frac {mg}{A} $$

,where $A$ is area of the heel, $m$ - person mass. Solve equation for $h$ and you'll have an answer.

BTW, atmospheric pressure can be neglected here, because it adds up to the **both** sides of equation. I.e. +1 atm also presses human with heels standing on the ground.

Comment: I solved the equation for h and the answer is 4 meters, right?

Comment: Nope, your calculations is by a couple orders of magnitude wrong. Re-check your solution by applying dimensional analysis - Did $h$ evaluates in meters ? Also check what exact values for parameters you have supplied ? Did water density was $997 ~kg/m^3$, etc ?